# How to get a list of available voices for Azure Text To Speech?

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

Is there a way to programatically list the available voices in Azure Text To Speech?

I've searched extensively and found this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support

But I have not found any way to get this information programatically - is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is `voices/list` endpoint and it is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech#get-a-list-of-voices).

Example from the documentation:

```
GET /cognitiveservices/voices/list HTTP/1.1

Host: westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer [Base64 access_token]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.16.0 there is...

[SpeechSynthesizer.GetVoicesAsync(string locale)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechsynthesizer.getvoicesasync)

```csharp
var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");            
using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, null as AudioConfig);
using var result = await synthesizer.GetVoicesAsync();
if (result.Reason == ResultReason.VoicesListRetrieved)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Found {result.Voices.Count} voices");
}
```

There is a working example SynthesisGetAvailableVoicesAsync() method in the Azure-Samples github respository... there is a direct link to the Text-to-Speech samples at the top of the [Text-to-speech quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech) page.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://westus.cris.ai/swagger/ui/index#/Language%20Generation%20Endpoints%3A/GetSupportedLocalesForLanguageGenerationEndpoints) mentioned in the swagger, you could use the

```
api/languagegeneration/v2.0/Endpoints/locales
```

end point to get the supported locales.

```
/api/texttospeech/v2.0/datasets/locales
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I tried, but there's not enough informatio  here to actually come up with a solution - would you mind providing more detail please?

Answer (score 0):

With python SDK, you can get the list of available voices via `get_voices_async` method on `SpeechSynthesizer` class.

`get_voices_async` method ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.speechsynthesizer?view=azure-python#azure-cognitiveservices-speech-speechsynthesizer-get-voices-async)) returns a future `ResultFuture` ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.resultfuture?view=azure-python)) that you can await by calling `get` method on it.

In this case, the `get` method returns `SynthesisVoicesResult` object ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.synthesisvoicesresult?view=azure-python))

You can retrieve list of available voices from voices property in `SynthesisVoicesResult` object, which is a list of `VoiceInfo` object ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.voiceinfo?view=azure-python)).

```py
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

# config
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=<your_api_key>, region=<your_region>)

# Create your client
client = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config)

# Request the list of available voices
voices_result = client.get_voices_async().get()

# iterate through the list of voices
print([v.local_name for v in result.voices])
```

Similar api calls exist with the other language SDKs.